# Traversing a list data dynamically in Pyomo Abstract Model

Tags: optimization, modeling, pyomo, constraint-programming, parameter

In my PYOMO abstract model, I am reading my data file and storing some specific attributes in a list say **demand=[]**.

I am reading the data file as follows:

```
 for node in G.nodes:
    demand.append(G.nodes[node]["demand"])
 print(demand)
```

I am getting the output as **[10, 12, 22, 5, 2]**

Now I want to store the values in the list as individual parameters for my model such as:

```
model.d1=10
model.d2=12
```

and so on.

Can you guide me on the logic for storing these values as individual parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using the INDEXED COMPONENT concept of Pyomo.

```
model.d = Param(demand, within=NonNegativeIntegers)
```

The Pyomo book explains this in chapter 3 and it is available at [1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-68928-5)